# What is the difference between child and body properties in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I followed a tutorial in which they demonstrated two widgets: a `Scaffold` and a `FloatingActionButton`.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
      )
```

Here we are using the `child` property to specify the icon.

`body: Text("Hello world"),`

Here we are using `body` inside the `Scaffold`.

What is the difference between `child` and `body` and where do we use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between child and body and where do we use
> them?

They are just different names.

Most widgets in flutter use `child` or `children` to represent the `Widget` that should be rendered below the widget in the WidgetTree, but in the case of `Scaffold` the property is named body, to make it clear that the body widget will be rendered as the body or the largest part of the screen in the app as `Scaffold` also accepts appBar, floating action button, etc.

What's important here is that whether `body` or `child` they are both of type `Widget`